# Find height and width of pdf using iTextSharp

Tags: vb.net

In my window application i am using Quick pdf to find height,width of pdf.please refer the below code.But sometimes quickpdf can't able to find correct value.so i want to do the task using iTextSharp. How to find pdf height,width using iTextSharp?

Try

```
        Dim qp1 As New iSED.QuickPDF
        Dim sPDFHei, sPDFWid As Double
        Dim iPgCnt As Integer
        qp1.UnlockKey("6510E9D5C3938A920B3A8D7293C6DF00")
        qp1.LoadFromFile(sFilePath & "\" & cmbArticles.Text)
        qp1.SetMeasurementUnits(0)
        iPgCnt = qp1.PageCount
        For i As Integer = 1 To iPgCnt
            'MsgBox("pagecount=" & iPgCnt)
            qp1.SelectPage(i)
            'MsgBox("PageNumber=" & i)

            sPDFHei = qp1.PageHeight : sPDFWid = qp1.PageWidth
            sPDFHei = Math.Round(sPDFHei, 2) : sPDFWid = Math.Round(sPDFWid, 2)

            ''If sPDFWid <> 8.26 And sPDFHei <> 11.69 Then
            If sPDFWid > 520 Or sPDFHei > 600 Then
                MsgBox("Article PDF size should not exit 7.22 x 8.33" & vbCrLf & "Problem in template:" & i)
                Exit Function
            End If
        Next
        qp1.clear()


        Checkpdfsize = True
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Information, "CheckPdfSize")
    End Try
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Youll find what you need in chapter 6 of their documentation [here](http://manning.com/lowagie2/samplechapter6.pdf). Its under Action by the way.